# How to simplify lemma

Tags: coq

I have problem in solving the lemma `list_value`.
Destruct command gives complicated situation. How I
can proceed? Any sub_lemma could be
helpful? Function `G_value` is zero only, when list is empty.
Therefore I have put constraint that list cannot be nil.
current_value function confirms that, all elemnts in
list nat are less or equal to the greatest value determine by `G_value`.

```
Definition change_h (n: nat) (l: list nat) : list nat:=
    match l with
    | nil => l
    | h::tl => if n <=? h then l else n::tl
     end.
      Fixpoint G_value (n: nat) (l: list nat) {struct n}: nat :=
    match l with
     | nil => 0
     | cons s nil => s 
     | cons h l => match n with
     | O => h
     | S n' => G_value n' (change_h h l)
     end
   end.

     Theorem list_value :forall(n n0:nat) ( l:list nat),
     (length l=?0)=false ->
     (length l - length l =? 0)=true ->
     (current_value 0 0 (n :: l) <=? n) = true.
     Proof.
    intros. unfold current_value.
    simpl in *.

      1 subgoal
      n, n0 : nat
      l : list nat
      H : (length l =? 0) = false
      H0 : (length l - length l =? 0) = true
      ______________________________________(1/1)
      ( (if
       match l with
       | [ ] => n
       | _ :: _ => G_value (length l) (change_h n l)
       end =? 0
      then 0
      else
      match l with
      | [ ] => n
      | _ :: _ => G_value (length l) (change_h n l)
      end) <=? n) = true
```

Comment: what's the definition of `current_value`? Please also fix the indentationt make the code easier to read.

Comment: Can you edit your question to improve it?

Comment: change_h function swap high value with h,therefore
all values in the list are less or equal, than value
exist at head of list.I want to prove following lemma 

Theorem value_le_n :forall (n a :nat)(l:list nat),
(G_value (length (a :: l))
(change_h n (a :: l)) <=? n) = true.